# pl/sql displaying all columns of a table

Tags: plsql

```
employee table schema

employee(id, name, company, salary);
```

procedure created to display all the column values

```
create or replace procedure p1
IS
BEGIN
  select * from employee;
END;
/

exe p1;
```

However, this does not display the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PL/SQL block is not valid, and won't even run. You need to either return the data back to the client, or if you're using SQL*Plus use [dbms_output.put_line](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm) to print the query resultset.

```
create or replace procedure p1
IS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  FOR emp_rec in select * from employee LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line('EMployee id: || emp_rec.emp_id || ' Name: ' || emp_rec ename);
  END LOOP
END;
/
```

Change the column name suitably